# Django utf8 DatabaseError occurred when a database character set already set to utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, django

Each time I edit a model with string attributes then migrate, the error comes. But the character set of the database and its tables already set to utf8mb4. For example, I wanted to add "related_name" to authors field, the error occurred.

```
class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    pub_date = models.DateField()

    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    language = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    print_length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='by')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (3719, "3719: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.", None)
```

Database status:

```
mysql> show create database eShop;
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                                              |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| eShop    | CREATE DATABASE `eShop` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use utf8mb4. It will avoid the confusion when utf8 changes from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4.

**UPDATE**

Along with setting 'CHARSET' in OPTIONS, seems like there is additional change needs to be made.

Indexes in InnoDB tables can't be longer than 255 chars with utf8, but only 191 chars with utf8mb4. This means that the default indexes that Django makes for CharField(max_length=255) is too long, and might break things.

You will need to update the VARCHAR length if to less than 191 if it is set to 255 now.

---

Right now, mysql reserves 3 bytes encoded UTF-8 (UTF8MB3) per character, but you can force it to reserve 4 bytes using UTF8MB4. The future default for 'utf-8' will be UTF8MB4. That is why it is recommended to consider the warning and make the changes.

To fix this issue, use OPTIONS entry in the Django DATABASE setting, and specify which charset to use

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'USER': 'xxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',  # The characterset you need
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ahh!! try adding 'use_unicode' = TRUE under 'charset' option and then migrate?

Comment: Ok, i dont know if this will work.. but I read this is an issue with MySql. If your field is VarChar(255) , can you set it to 191 ? it seems max length for UTF8MB4 is 191

Comment: it worked! but there is another issue - "django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Failed to set SDI 'eShop.book_book_authors' in tablespace 'eshop/book_book_authors'.".

Comment: ahh seems like a different problem. I will check about it. but for this specific question, let me edit the answer and you can accept it.. so that if someone comes across same.. they know how to fix this.

Comment: yeah sure, I'm new do I need to do something to allow you to edit your answer or you can just edit it directly?

Comment: I fixed the new issue, don't worry about that.